# Does this fit "best practices" for MVC routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a web application which can be used by multiple clients. We want the URL for, say, Client1, to appear like this:

http://www.blah.com/client1/.....

and for Client2 to appear like this:

http://www.blah.com/client2/

And so forth. So I set up my routing table to be like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Company",
            url: "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {company = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So that's the first question. Does anybody see any problems with how I've got the routing tables setup thus far? If someone specifies a company name "ClientX" I want to make sure the first route is executed, otherwise if they only specify a controller/action, then I want the second route to be executed.

My next question is whether it's considered bad form to get the company name they specified in the way I'm doing it.

I have a base Controller and within its Initialize method I do the following:

```
        protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
          if(requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("company"))
          {
            CompanyName = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["company"]; 
          }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        }
```

"CompanyName" is a property:

```
public string CompanyName { get; private set; }
```

I've never messed with the default routing in MVC before (I've never needed to) and I want to make sure I'm not doing something dumb.

Answer (score 0):

The route table is ok, this is how it's usually done in MVC areas and Web API. All good here.

However the initializing of the company in the controller, it's not bad, it's just that usually you add an action parameter called company of type string to the action method. If all or many of the actions in the controller need this bit of information then it's better to read it in the initialization phase like you did. Here, it's up to you. It works both ways.